# Android Toolbar subtitle depending on selected Tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

I'm smashing my head on this problem.

My app has a Navigation Drawer and a Navigation Tab just under the Toolbar.
I want to show a subtitle in the Toolbar only when being in a determined tab (let's say the second one).

I've already implemented my TabPageAdapter extending FragmentPagerAdapter.
Then I wrote the code so that if I select a tab from the left Navigation Drawer, I can show the subtitle only in the second tab and hide it in the others.

[image: My Navigation Drawer]

The problem is that I can't show/hide the subtitle by selecting tabs directly from the Navigation Tab.
In fact, even by using

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(null);
```

and

```
String subtitle = //my subtitle;
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(subtitle);
```

in the fragments of each tab, the whole code doesn't work.
I think the problem is with the FragmentPagerAdapter (and the FragmentStatePagerAdapter): their

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position);
```

method is keeping in memory the other two tabs, too.

My **getItem(int position)** method is this one:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment;

    switch (position) {

        case MAP_POSITION:
            fragment = MapFragment.newInstance(MAP_TYPE);
            return fragment;

        case PETROL_POSITION:
            fragment = PetrolStationListFragment.newInstance(position);
            return fragment;

        case FAV_POSITION:
            return new FavouritesFragment();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Any hints?

Comment: is your `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is an inner class inside the Activity?

Comment: The FragmentPagerAdapter is inside of a Fragment, which I named TabFragment.
I'm using an Activity (the MainActivity) a two nested fragments: the one containing the Tab Navigator and the one containing the argument of the selected tab (i.e.: Map, PetrolStations or Favourites).